# Add different number of TextViews to LinearLayout holder in ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-linearlayout

I have a listview with CustomArrayAdapter,

want to add dynamically different amount of TextViews to LinearLayout Holder in that listView (like List of TextViews in each row)

```
  @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    //String menu_opcja = getItem(position);
    SupleSubClass supleSubClass = getItem(position);


    if (convertView==null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.suplementacja_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.suplement = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nazwa_suplementu);
        holder.opis = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.descr);
        holder.linearLayout = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_test);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.suplement.setText(supleSubClass.getName());
    holder.opis.setText(supleSubClass.getDescr());
    holder.linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);


    return convertView;

}


private static class ViewHolder{
    TextView suplement;
    TextView opis;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;

}
```

[image]

Comment: dont you want to use an `ExpandableListView`?

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many types of layout you will need it is possible to use method:

```
getViewTypeCount()
```

This method should return total number of unique layouts.

The next step is creating method:

```
getItemViewType(int position)
```

that will inform which layout to use for given position.

In getView() you need to inflate layout only if it is null and determine layout by getItemViewType(position)

For details, refer to [this tutorial](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296)